# Identify names in a string

Tags: search, annotations, nlp, chunking

I would like to find a good way of identifying names of people, places, etc. within users search queries on my site.  For example, if a user asks "how old is George Washington", I need to be able to know from a predefined list that George Washington is a person.

Some of the lists will be global, and some will be user specific.  For example, if they asked "how old is John Smith" I may only want to identify the particular John Smith that is my associate--and I wouldn't want to identify him as a person if he's not my associate.

Is there any NLP library or crawling of these lists I could do to leverage Soundx, mature NLP, misspell, etc. functionality?  I can write it by hand, but I would rather leverage something mature.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need is called `Named Entity Recognition`

One of the best available software to do it comes with Stanford NLP:
http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/CRF-NER.shtml
(written in Java)

If you are on another platform, there are good open source projects in Ruby and Python. Search for "Named Entity Recognition".

Answer (score 2):

The particular Natural Language Processing (NLP) task that you're looking for is called `Named Entity Recognition` (NER)

Other than the Stanford's [CRF-NER](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/CRF-NER.shtml) (in java), a popular python choice from `Natural Language ToolKit` ([NLTK](http://nltk.org/install.html)) is often used as a baseline for NER tasks.

You can try installing NLTK then execute the following code:

```
>>> from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
>>> from nltk.tag import pos_tag
>>> from nltk.chunk import ne_chunk
>>> sentence = "How old is John Smith?"
>>> ne_chunk(pos_tag(word_tokenize(sentence)))
Tree('S', [('How', 'WRB'), ('old', 'JJ'), ('is', 'VBZ'), Tree('PERSON', [('John', 'NNP'), ('Smith', 'NNP')]), ('?', '.')])
```

Comment: this only find name start with capital letter, can we also find name start with small latel ?

Comment: @GEITPL_Dev, you can use Capitalization Support in Python Human Name Parser, link: http://nameparser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#capitalization-support